# AspNetCore api Versioning MapToApiVersion not descovered but still able to hit the route

Tags: c#, .net-core, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

Please consider the following case.

Because version 1.0 is not defined on the controller in a ApiVersionAttribute it is not discovered a not declare an API version. Just like i want because from this moment on **i don't want to support this version any longer**. My swagger documentation that is dependen on the IApiVersionDescriptionProvider works correctly and is no longer generating documentation for version1. When i make a api call to version 2.1 and check the returned version headers there is also only the supported version 2.1 & the deprecated version 2.0. Just as excpected.

But when i make a call to **version 1.0 i still hit the endpoint** and the apiversion still doesn't return 1.0 as a supported version.
I was hoping this would **return a 400 bad request with the "UnsupportedApiVersion" error message** and with the headers descriping the versions 2.0&2.1.

The reason i was exploring this behavior is that we want to make it possible to upgrade our microservice versions through adding the ApiVersionAttribute for certain version at runtime through some configuration. So we don't need to make a new build because the Getdefault route will be mapped for those higher apiversions.

```
//  Declare both versions
[ApiVersion("2.0", Deprecated = true)]
[ApiVersion("2.1")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/HelloWorld")] // Support path versioning
[ApiController]
public class HelloWorldController : ControllerBase
{

    //  Map to v1.0
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public string Get1() => "v1.0";

    //  Map to v2.0
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    public string Get2() => "v2.0";

    //  Map to all versions defined on the controller that not already have a mapping
    public string Getdefault() => $"{forExamplePerposeHereIsVersionReturned}";
}
```

(package used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning)

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because a route still exists for `v1.0/HelloWorld` and **Get1** maps to this version. API Versioning doesn't change routing, it merely allows matching and disambiguating otherwise duplicate routes by API version metadata. Although `1.0` is no longer *declared*, the fact that a valid route still exists for it and maps to the corresponding version results in a match.

The *proper* way to remove this API/action when it is no longer valid would be to remove the action (e.g. the code). That is the default expectation.

There are a couple of approaches that are possible to make things *appear* dynamic. You could use custom *conventions* to only declare and/or map API versions based on some type of configuration. This can be done with the API Versioning *Conventions* API or you can add your own custom convention. Another approach would be to register a custom **IActionDescriptorProvider** that runs last and removes the **ActionDescriptor** for APIs that no longer apply by inspecting their associated version information. This information is retrieved by getting the **ApiVersionModel** via the `ActionDescriptor.GetApiVersionModel` extension method.

---

> UPDATE: While this is the behavior, it was actually a bug. An API version that is only *mapped* should not be routed.

> The bug was reported in [Issue 735](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/735). In **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning** `5.1`, the response will now be `400`. In **Asp.Versioning.Http** or **Asp.Versioning.Mvc**, the response will be `404`.